# wxEasyHTMLPrinting html support

Tags: html, printing, wxpython

I am currently developing some simple invoice generator app, but I am stucked on printing. I read about printing in `wxPython` but everything looks unnecessary complicated for my purposes. So I found something about `wxEasyHTMLPrinting`, which looks really good, but I cannot find which html features are supported. So could you point me to some info about it? And is css (some basic styles) supported?

I was unable to find some more complex example as this http://wiki.wxpython.org/Printing :(
Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at wx.HTMLEasyPrinting but found it both too simplistic and too complicated to use. May have just been me.

But instead I developed a banded report writer like Crystal Reports that combines data like that you get from cur.fetchall() and a xml-based report form file and outputs PDF. You can take that PDF and preview it, email it, fax it, or print it, all using code.

If you are interested, it is part of a larger framework called Dabo. There's even a sample invoice report to get you started. http://dabodev.com or https://github.com/dabodev/dabo